# How to deal with non-English questions?

Tags: discussion

Example:
[Problems accessing my funds with Ethereum Wallet 0.3.9](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/probl%c3%a8me-wallet-ethereum-wallet-win64-0-3-9)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an English-language site so questions must be posted in English. If non-English questions are posted, leave a thoughtful comment and close it as *unclear what you are asking.*

Comment: Now that the *unclear what you are asking* close reason has been retired, the nearest equivalent would be *Needs details or clarity*.

Answer (score -2):

Mo Chairde
(my friends in Irish)

if the goal is to provide the pre-eminent location for all things technical Ethereum then surely it is incumbent on 'us' to devise a method for non English speakers rather than a 'carte blanche' English only...

..here are the Top 10 world speakers in M and % of world population

1   Mandarin    935 (955)   14.1%
2   Spanish 390 (405)   5.85%
3   English 365 (360)   5.52%
4   Hindi   295[3] (310)[4] 4.46%
5   Arabic  280 (295)   4.23%
6   Portuguese  205 (215)   3.08%
7   Bengali 200 (205)   3.05%
8   Russian 160 (155)   2.42%
9   Japanese    125 (125)   1.92%
10  Punjabi 95 (100)    1.44%

Source:: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers

It follows then we should (over time) add moderators who are multi lingual or even mono lingual who can moderate / answer in one of the Top 10 world languages.

Go raibh maith agat
Literally “May you have goodness or simply Thanks in Irish

Comment: This is a general problem with stackoverflow and the solution has been to create language specific sites, e.g. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/. Unfortunately I can't see many other sites having enough users to sustain language specific versions.

Comment: This suggestion is silly. Assuming that most people only speak one or two of those languages and questions would be evenly spread, people would only be able to even understand 10-20% of the content. I'd not be interested in using a page where I can't even understand 80-90% of the content. It follows then that we focus on collecting content in one language. And instead of looking at the number of native speakers, we look at the [total number of speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_total_number_of_speakers), excluding Chinese English is the most widely used language.

Comment: This assumption is silly.. assuming the users are per the number of native speakers or the total number of speakers it would follow then that the number of questions would be weighted accordingly..i.e. the highest % would be English